# Update statement with subquery from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update a column in a table.  The goal is take the current value and subtract the value from a different table.  Here's what I'm looking at:

```
update LS   
    set LS.Quantity = (LS.Quantity - 
    ( 
        select top 1 LSM.Quantity 
        from tblLocationStockMovement LSM
            join tblLocation L on L.ID=LSM.LocationID
            join tblStock S on S.ID=LSM.StockID
            join tblLocationStock LS on LS.StockID=LSM.StockID
        where 
            LSM.StockID=LS.StockID 
            and MoveTypeID=16
            and dateadd(DAY, DATEDIFF(day,0,DateCreated),0)='2016-08-30 00:00:00.00')
    )

from tblLocationStock LS    
    join tblLocation L on L.ID=LS.LocationID
    join tblStock S on S.ID=LS.StockID
    join tblLocationStockMovement LSM on LS.StockID=LSM.StockID
```

The `tblLocationStockMovement` table has the value I need to subtract from the `tblLocationStock` table.  Both of them can be joined to `tblStock` using `StockID`.  I'm hoping that it will subtract the value for the same stock that is referenced in both tables.  Right now it just does the same number for every item.

I probably don't need the `join`s at the end, I'm just using that to add a `where` to test a specific item before I do it for every item.  Do you see where I'm going wrong?

Edit: Thanks David for fixing my formatting.  I haven't used this site much so I'm not familiar with the proper way to post things.

Edit2 :

All three of you have a similar idea, and the strange thing is that it *sometimes* works.

Here's what I'm running now:

```
update LS
     set LS.Quantity=(ISNULL(LS.Quantity,0)-ISNULL(LSM.Quantity,0))
         from tblLocationStock LS
             join tblLocation L on L.ID=LS.LocationID
             join tblStock S on S.ID=LS.StockID
             join tblLocationStockMovement LSM on LSM.StockID=S.ID
         where L.LongDescription='Cafe'
             and MoveTypeID=2
             and PLU = 715
```

The problem is the result changes and I don't know why.

```
select LSM.Quantity
from tblLocationStockMovement LSM
     join tblLocation L on L.ID=LSM.LocationID
     join tblStock S on S.ID=LSM.StockID
where L.LongDescription='Cafe'
    and PLU=715
    and MoveTypeID=2
```

Always results in 120.

```
 select LS.Quantity
    from tblLocationStock LS
        join tblLocation L on L.ID=LS.LocationID
        join tblStock S on S.ID=LS.StockID
    where L.LongDescription='Cafe'
        and PLU = 715
```

Always results in 53.  So, you would expect the result of the update statement to always result in -67.  Sometimes it does, but sometimes I'll get 5,-43, or 29.  Is there a reason why the answer would differ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
UPDATE LS   
    SET LS.Quantity = (LS.Quantity-LSM.Quantity)
FROM tblLocationStockMovement LSM
JOIN tblLocation L ON L.ID=LSM.LocationID
JOIN tblStock S ON S.ID=LSM.StockID
JOIN tblLocationStock LS ON LS.StockID=LSM.StockID
WHERE LSM.StockID=LS.StockID 
    AND MoveTypeID=16
    AND dateadd(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,DateCreated),0)='2016-08-30 00:00:00.00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update LS   
    set LS.Quantity = ISNULL(LS.Quantity,0) - ISNULL(LSM.Quantity,0)
from tblLocationStock LS    
join tblLocation L on L.ID=LS.LocationID
join tblStock S on S.ID=LS.StockID
join tblLocationStockMovement LSM on LS.StockID=LSM.StockID
    and MoveTypeID=16
    and dateadd(DAY, DATEDIFF(day,0,DateCreated),0)='2016-08-30 00:00:00.00'
```